# List Control Find ItemText MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a List Control in MFC.

With that code:

```
m_Eintrag3 = m_List.InsertItem(0, _T ("Schaller"));
m_List.SetItemText (m_Eintrag3, 1, _T ("Benedikt"));
m_List.SetItemText (m_Eintrag3, 2, _T ("05.08.1996"));
```

I can insert an Item and Text in my List Control.
With that code:

```
if ((m_List.FindItem(&Finde)) != -1)
```

I can find an Item. But I want to find ItemText. Not just the Item.
Is there any solution? FindItemText doesnt exist.

Comment: MSDN Docs for [CListCtrl::FindItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xetd6cd(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an example to search item text -- or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own loop, that checks the Subitems too... FindItem only works on the Item entry. Never on subitems.